# Swift UITableViewCell with reusable components

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to write an UITableViewCell programmatically with reusable components that I call "cards".
The "cards" uses AutoLayout.

I created a UITableViewCell class:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let card = NoticeCardView()
        contentView.addSubview(card)

        card.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        card.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        card.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        card.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
}

func setValues(notice : Notice) {
        card.setValues(notice: notice)
}
```

I create the cell in the controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : NoticeListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "noticeCell", for: indexPath) as! NoticeListCell

        let notice = notList[indexPath.row]
        cell.setValues(notice: notice)
        return cell;
    }
```

The result is that the "card" is correctly rendered but the "cell" maintains the original height of 44 that is the value set by UITableViewAutomaticDimension.
If I put in the UITableViewCell the whole "card" definition all works well but I don't have a reusable component.
Someone have an idea or used a design like this?

Comment: How does NoticeListCell look like? Did you set the constraints inside correctly?

Comment: how does it work without constraints?

Comment: The constraints of the card are correct. The debugger don't show any problem and the card is correctly rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you forgot to set card's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
  super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

  let card = NoticeCardView()
  // Add this line and it will work
  card.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  contentView.addSubview(card)

  card.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
  card.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
  card.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
  card.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but the result is worse. The cell assumes an height of 5.

Comment: My solution just makes your constraints work .I don't know how NoticeCardView is implemented but as I guess, problem is because you don't set heightAnchor for card. I think if you give card a heightAnchor constraints, it will resolve problem

Comment: Mate, you are great. The problem was exactly what you suggest. I created the card as a floating shape because I forgot to connect the shape to self, that is the window the represent my card. I inserted the right constraints and all went ok. Many thanks